# Parse User.Login never gets called?

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, authentication, parse-platform

I'm simply trying to Log in with a user I've just created in Parse.

I know the user is valid, I know the function gets called.

This is what I tried:

```
// V1
Parse.User.logIn("username", "password").then(function(user) {
  console.log("Logged in");
}, function(error) {
  console.log("Error logging in");
});

// V2
Parse.User.logIn("username", "password", {
  success: function(user) {
    console.log("Logged in");
  },
  error: function(user, error) {
    console.log("Error logging in");
  }
});
```

And neither of the console logs show up, success or failure...

Is there something I'm missing?

Thanks!

Comment: did you look up the documentation for `Parse.User.logIn`?

Comment: Yea but thats exactly what it says to do no?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was in fact due to the asynchronous nature of the Parse.User.Login code, had to work with it as a promise

For others having this issue: http://blog.parse.com/2013/01/29/whats-so-great-about-javascript-promises/